# Datatables are not showing data retrieved by Json

Tags: php, jquery, datatables

I wrote this code in a `PHP` file named `anggotabckend.php?action=save`

```
$array  = array('satu'=>'1','dua'=>'2','tiga'=>'3');
    $jsoned = json_encode($array);
    echo $jsoned;
```

Then I wrote this code in `Datatables`

```
$('table#loadeddata').DataTable({
    "ajax": "anggotabckend.php?action=save",
    "columns": [
        {data: 'satu' },
        {data: 'dua' }]
});
```

the link written in `"ajax"` is correct, the column is correct, but when I tried to retrieve data, the `Datatables` ended up with endless loading or sometimes showed no data available. What have I done wrong with this thing?

Comment: The ajax is **not** coded correctly, there is no function to process the returned data [look at the manual](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) for the `.done` function

Comment: Should I place the datatatables function inside a done function?

Answer (score 0):

jQuery DataTables expects data to be array of arrays or array of objects and formatted in a certain way, see [Data source types](http://datatables.net/manual/data#Data-source-types).

Use the code below:

```
$array  = array('satu'=>'1','dua'=>'2','tiga'=>'3');
$jsoned = json_encode(array('data' => array($array)));

header("Content-type: application/json");
echo $jsoned;
```

Comment: On which line in the manual the format for array written? I couldn't find it

Comment: @januaryananda, see [`Ajax`](http://datatables.net/manual/ajax#Data-array-location) section.